# How to pass class type as property

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

`public class Myclass 
{ 
Public Type type {get;set;}
}`

While Json serialisation I am getting error “Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Type”

Can some one help me out here ?

Comment: can you provide an example of the json where you get the exception if you try to parse it?

Comment: I doubt you want to deserialize a `Type`, but rather a types name which you can then deconstruct to a `Type`, do you?

Answer (score 0):

to support that easiest way (not tested) should be (assuming you are on Newtonsoft.Json):

```
public class MyClass
{
  private string _type;

  [JsonIgnore]
  public Type type {get => Assembly.GetType(_type, true, false); set => value.Fullname;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own Converter. Take a look on this example and implement on your way.

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonTypeConverter))]
    public Type Type { get; set; }
}

public class JsonTypeConverter: JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var type = value as Type;
        writer.WriteValue(type.Name);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Type);
    }
}
```

Comment: please, provide a stack trace